# Using NetInfo to check users online and offline not working

Tags: react-native

I get offline only and it doesn't show what users are online. I tried asking ChatGPT but it gave me answers that don't work, here is its response:

> In the code you shared, the list of users fetched from the server is being updated with the socket connection's online/offline events. However, it seems like there is a problem with the logic inside the event listeners.

```js
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, AppState } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

const SOCKET_URL = 'http://10.100.102.23:3002';

const DATA = [
    { id: '1', name: 'John Doe' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Jane Smith' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Bob Johnson' },
    // Add more contacts as needed
];

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
);

export default function MentorsChat() {
    const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Create a WebSocket connection
        const socket = io(SOCKET_URL);

        // Save the socket object in the state
        setSocket(socket);

        // Fetch the list of users
        axios
            .get('http://10.100.102.23:3002/api/users')
            .then(response => {
                setUsers(response.data.map(user => {
                    const isUserOnline = socket && socket.connected && socket.id === user.socketId;
                    return { ...user, isOnline: isUserOnline };
                }));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });


        // Listen to the 'online' event
        socket.on('online', userId => {
            setUsers(prevState => {
                return prevState.map(user => {
                    if (user._id === userId) {
                        return { ...user, isOnline: true };
                    } else {
                        return user;
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // Listen to the 'offline' event
        socket.on('offline', userId => {
            setUsers(prevState => {
                return prevState.map(user => {
                    if (user._id === userId) {
                        return { ...user, isOnline: false };
                    } else {
                        return user;
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // Close the socket connection when the component unmounts
        return () => {
            if (socket) {
                socket.close();
            }
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Listen to network state changes
        const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
            setIsOnline(state.isConnected);
            if (state.isConnected) {
                updateAllIsOnline(true);
            } else {
                updateAllIsOnline(false);
            }
        });

        // Clean up the listener when the component unmounts
        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    const updateAllIsOnline = (isOnline) => {
        setUsers(prevState =>
            prevState.map(user => ({ ...user, isOnline }))
        );
    };

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        const backgroundColor = item.id === selectedId ? "#6e3b6e" : "#f9c2ff";

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelectedId(item.id)} style={[styles.item, { backgroundColor }]}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.fullName}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{item.isMentor ? "Mentor" : "Not a mentor"}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{item.isOnline ? "Online" : "Offline"}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );

    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={users}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.fullName.toString()}_${item.isMentor.toString()}`}
                extraData={selectedId}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
    },
    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
        padding: 20,
        marginVertical: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have no other solution that manually asking for connection check. The only think worked for me is requesting before every request if I'm still online or not.

```
const checkConnection = () => {
    NetInfo.refresh().then((state) => {
        if (!state.isConnected) {
            // Not connected
        } else {
            // Connected
        }
    });
};
```

For some reasons, observer/listener on `NetInfo` just doesn't work and it was not reliable in my use case. This is **not** a solution BTW, but it works.

You can always pass some callback functions to that `checkConnection` or make it `async` and `await` for `NetInfo.refresh()`